# "Performance Based Health Management" Incentive Programs

Tags: benefits, health

My employer just announced that for next year there will be a performance based health care incentive program.  This will include an initial screening (BMI calculation, basic blood panel, etc) and require some input from us throughout the year regarding our level of physical activity and diet.

Personally, I love the idea.  I work very hard to be as healthy as possible so I'd love to benefit from a program like this.

However, since they just announced the program, they aren't giving us any specifics about what the incentives will be.  What form do these incentives typically take?

Comment: When you said 'performance based healthcare incentives' I read this as "the better you perform, the more healthcare coverage you get"? I assume this is more like "visit the gym ten times and get a free tote bag"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is highly localized to the OP's company and not useful for the stack exchange community at large.

Comment: I obviously disagree about it being off topic since I posted it.  I think that hearing about how other companies handle these types of programs so I can evaluate the one I am being offered is relevant to the overall topic of 'navigating the workplace'.

Comment: [Related question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/15409/2322) which has some good related information.

Comment: I've heard of discounts/tax breaks when you have a gym membership.

Comment: @Kevin You're essentially polling the community rather than asking a specific question, correct?

Comment: I suppose that is one way of describing my goal.  Although, isn't asking the community about their experience with similar programs fundamentally the same as soliciting opinions about salary negotiation tactics or dealing with annoying coworkers?  Both situations could be described as 'polling' the community since they are likely to spawn multiple responses with no definitive answer.

Comment: Kevin, I think it may help to read [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). The big difference is that a poll doesn't explain *why* or *how* whereas explaining negotiating tactics does. You also may want to read [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) to see how to turn a poll in to a question that explains *why/how*. Also note our [help/dont-ask]: *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**."* What is your problem?

Comment: This still feels like a borderline poll even after editing it to remove the trigger words; it still might not fit our format, but it's a *great* question. I closed it before really thinking it through and making my edits, which do make the post feel a little more Q&A. So I reopened to give it a second chance. We'll see if it can get good answers. If the community puts it on hold again, I'll leave it closed. Good luck! :)

Comment: While it may not be literally a question, the topic is highly relevant.  The US Air Force had tried this idea in the mid-1990s after their researchers found out a lot of people were out of shape.  They attempted to impose certain objectives on officers and airmen, and ended up with a lot of problems, including lawsuits. I was working on the data collection tool that would have recorded all this during the baseline measurement phase.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Guessing what benefits your company is going to offer.  There is no real problem to solve here.

Comment: Run away from this company as fast as you can. This is the first step towards making your health insurance depend on your lifestyle. You really don't want to be at a place when a negative heallth condition or unapproved lifestyle can give you higher rates the next year. That defeats the entire purpose of health insurance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm just curious what they are like. Are they discounts on your
>   monthly insurance premiums? A check in the mail if you meet the
>   program goals? A trendy backpack with the company logo and a yearly
>   supply of low-fat salad dressing?

As I understand it, different companies offer different rewards. While I don't know any that offer a supply of salad dressing, I do know some that offer money, and some that offer company swag.

Where I currently work, they have a "Wellness Program", championed by HR. You attain "bonus points" for certain activities deemed "healthy" by the company. For example, if you have an annual physical, you get 50 points. If you have your biometric screening performed (BMI, cholesterol, blood pressure, etc), you get 125 points. And so on, and so on.

Once you get 300 points, you are given $250. And your spouse can earn $250 the same way.

From an HR point of view, this improves the health of the company, is generally viewed as a "nice thing to do for employees", leads to a reduction in absences, and perhaps a future reduction in insurance premiums.

I don't know the participation rate, although I'm sure it's less than 50%.